# Runnin docker build generates the following error "unknown instruction: EXPAND-ARCHIVE"

Tags: docker

I have to say that I'm new to Docker and Dockerfiles... I need to create a build that has a nano server and java installed.
I've created the following docker file, but I got the error below

Here's the file

```
# Installer image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 AS installer

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]


RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile java.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.2+8/d4173c853231432d94f001e99d882ca7/jdk-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin.zip;`
    Expand-Archive java.zip -DestinationPath java; `
```

And the error is

`Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 8: unknown instruction: EXPAND-ARCHIVE`

What am I doing wrong? I'm on a Windows Container runtime

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's documentation now mention to use the \ to escape over multiple lines

```
RUN Write-Host "pwsh .bak copied across"; \
    Get-ChildItem -Path /var/opt/mssql/backup \
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery" \
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "SELECT * from sys.databases" \
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile#escape-character

Answer (score 1):

Changed it to the following and tested. the error is gone.

```
# Installer image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:10.0.14300.1030 AS installer

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; 
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]


RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile java.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.2+8/d4173c853231432d94f001e99d882ca7/jdk-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin.zip;
CMD [ "Expand-Archive", "java.zip", "-DestinationPath java;" ]
```

Comment: Thanks @blackrain, but do you know why this happen? I took as example this https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/2.1/aspnet/nanoserver-1809/amd64/Dockerfile and it doesn't use the CMD

Comment: I read the docs from here to try the fix. I am not sure why it doesn't work the way your wrote it. Since i followed the docs, i assumed that is the right way.
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile